# Why When I Print Dataset in TensorFlow Shows Many Array Eventhough I'm Only Printing The First

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory, tensorflow-datasets

I'm doing a tensorflow colab and I'm having problem understanding datasets especially after you normalize the data... in the "Explore Process Data" section. I'm using a for loop here to kind of understand the data being printed. When I do a for look and take one from dataset why is printing such a long dataset if the images is 28x28 and using numpy to print a 2d array representation of the data... here's the link to colab exercise using MNIST dataset 
https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/courses/udacity_intro_to_tensorflow_for_deep_learning/l03c01_classifying_images_of_clothing.ipynb

```
dataset, metadata = tfds.load('fashion_mnist', as_supervised=True, with_info=True)
train_dataset, test_dataset = dataset['train'], dataset['test']

class_names = ['T-shirt/top', 'Trouser', 'Pullover', 'Dress', 'Coat',
               'Sandal',      'Shirt',   'Sneaker',  'Bag',   'Ankle boot']

def normalize(images, labels):
  images = tf.cast(images, tf.float32)
  images /= 255
  return images, labels

# The map function applies the normalize function to each element in the train
# and test datasets
train_dataset =  train_dataset.map(normalize)
test_dataset  =  test_dataset.map(normalize)

# The first time you use the dataset, the images will be loaded from disk
# Caching will keep them in memory, making training faster
train_dataset =  train_dataset.cache()
test_dataset  =  test_dataset.cache()

for img, label in test_dataset.take(1):
  print(img.numpy().reshape((28,28)))
  break
```

Comment: I've ran your code and it seems to work fine. The printed array has shape 28x28

Comment: how to access the 2 or 3rd element in the dataset if you do test_dataset[0][1] will not return anything